# Disable Autocorrect with External Keyboard on iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard, bluetooth

Are there any smart workarounds to disable autocorrect automatically -- or near automatic -- while using an external keyboard on iOS?

By default iOS provides no way to do this [as seen here on the Apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7378442?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: One workaround: switch to emoji keyboard. Then I can type on the external keyboard without autocorrect. Major downside: The emoji keyboard cannot be hidden and covers half the screen.

Comment: @thilo right but perhaps another, similar keyboard would work and be better. Thanks for the idea, will check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now in iOS 10 (or perhaps iOS 9) you can set this specifically for your Hardware Keyboard. This setting is ONLY available if you have the keyboard plugged in! Anyway, it's under Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Hardware Keyboards

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with my Bluetooth keyboard.  I was able to turn those settings off for the hardware keyboard, but they did not appear to have actually stopped the autocorrections.  Does it have to be a keyboard that's physically plugged in or is it a feature that's only meaningful for the iPad Pro's smart keyboards?

Comment: But you're definitely in settings for "Hardware Keyboard"?

Comment: Definitely in "Hardware Keyboard".  Do I also need to turn off those settings in "All Keyboards"?  If so, how do I turn them back on for the software keyboards?

Comment: @cjm I need to confirm your findings. Last I checked my solution worked without anything special, but I'll have to recheck

Comment: It seems to be working now, maybe it was just me missing some mistake at 2am when I originally was going through the answers.

Comment: @cjm story of my life...

Answer (score 1):

Not without a jailbreak. The system doesn't change settings based on the presence of an external keyboard.

- Best I can figure, you should use Siri to open the keyboard settings and toggle it on or off.  Whether you're faster doing that or just tap tap tap probably depends on your network speed and your device and your skillet navigating the touch interface.

I don't see a way for workflow or another automation app to script a change to that setting unless/until apple exposes that setting to Siri control. "Siri, turn off auto correct setting". On iOS 9 Siri knows that is a setting, but can't automate it.